# Using the gtkmm package centos

Tags: gtkmm

AIn attempting to use gtkmm library (binding for the GTK in c++ ) , i had to look first if the package is installed, i typed :

$ rpm -qa | grep gtkmm

I got

gtkmm24-2.24.2-8

I was expecting to just find gtkmm-2.4 or something like Not gtkmm24-2.24 , my problem comes in when i include 
the compiler complains that there is no such file or directory.

my makefile is the following:

```
Objs= main.o HelloWorldWindow.o
CC= g++ -std=c++11 
DEBUG = -g
CFLAGS= -Wall -c $(DEBUG)
LFLAGS= -Wall $(DEBUG)


mmex : $(Objs)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(Objs) -o mmex `pkg-config gtkmm24-2.4 --libs`

HelloWorldWindow.o : HelloWorldWindow.h HelloWorldWindow.cpp
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) HelloWorldWindow.cpp `pkg-config gtkmm24-2.4 --cflags`

main.o : main.cpp
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) main.cpp `pkg-config gtkmm24-2.4 --cflags`

clear :
    rm $(Objs)
    rm *~
```

How do ijust compile the simple example i have :  ( main.cpp and class HelloWorldWindow)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would need the dev package. It might be gtkmm24-dev, for instance, or something similar. However, you should really try to use gtkmm 3.